# Updating Multiple Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like this :

```
------------------------
|id  | status    |value|
------------------------
|1   | Y         |10   |
|2   | N         |10   |
|3   | Y         |10   |
|4   | N         |10   |
|5   | N         |10   |
------------------------
```

For every `status = 'N'`, I'd like to add 3 to its value and set its status to `'Y'`. So, the outcome table should be:

```
------------------------
|id  | status    |value|
------------------------
|1   | Y         |10   |
|2   | Y         |13   |
|3   | Y         |10   |
|4   | Y         |13   |
|5   | Y         |13   |
------------------------
```

How can I do this in the best way in SQL Server?

Comment: Not much to this, did you try anything?  Pretty basic sql syntax using an `Update` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update your_table
set status = 'Y',
    value = value + 3
where status = 'N'
```

Comment: thanks! I don't know we can do 'value=value+3' in Sql Server. *facepalm*

Comment: @user3689529: you need to get yourself an introductory book to SQL Server and T-SQL and learn more about SQL Server!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any. But you learn a lot about SQL if you stay put to the SQL tags here and read the questions and answers. This is how I leaned very much.